# Code formatting not working properly in prettier-eslint

Tags: vue.js, vscode-extensions, prettier, prettier-eslint

I use prettier-eslint for code formatting in vscode. All major tags formatted succesfully when save. But some tags divide the tag and it's class to another code line. I won't to get the tag and class in the same line. How can I do that? below I added some code line to get understand.

[image]

I wan't to code format as a below attachment.

[image]

Comment: checkout `printWidth` option in the prettier settings